# Counting views (relational database)

Tags: php, mysql

table event_views

```
ID + EVENT_ID + VIEW_DATE + MEMBER_ID
```

table member_city_access

```
ID + MEMBER_ID + CITY_ID + PRIMARY(not PK) + VIEWING
```

table cities

```
ID + TITLE
```

I am trying to get the number of views for an event from members in a particular city.

This is what I have

```
SELECT COUNT(`event_views`.`id`) c FROM `event_views`
    LEFT JOIN `member_city_access` city ON city.`member_id` = `event_views`.`member_id`
    LEFT JOIN `cities` on cities.id = city.city_id WHERE (city.city_id = '92' AND city.`primary` = 'on')
    AND `event_views`.`view_date` >= '20131103'
    AND `event_views`.`view_date` < '20131110'
```

I want to know if I am using the right "JOINS" for the count since the numbers are not aligning with the events, so in my report it shows ( for 1 city )

```
EVENTS ADDED = 0 , EVENTS VIEWED = 3
```

Comment: Thank you. edited to show the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query returns all the views you have that match your where clause. If you want to separate them by event, you have to group by event:

```
SELECT `event_views`.`id`,COUNT(`event_views`.`id`) c
FROM `event_views`
LEFT JOIN `member_city_access` city 
     ON city.`member_id` = `event_views`.`member_id`
LEFT JOIN `cities` 
     ON cities.id = city.city_id
WHERE city.city_id = '92'
    AND city.`primary` = 'on'
    AND `event_views`.`view_date` >= '20131103'
    AND `event_views`.`view_date` < '20131110'
GROUP BY `event_views`.`id`
```

Comment: I see. added "GROUP BY" and it now returns 1

1

1

1

1

instead of a total

Comment: actually it did'nt work since I don't get a "COUNT" but a list of 1's

Comment: @maximl337. Probably this isn't the right column to group by then. What is the column you want to group by then? city.id?

Comment: good question. I think it should be event_view.id but I am unsure. I want to count all views from a specific city between those dates

Comment: @maximl337. You have to find out what is the column you want to group by when you are doing an aggregate function. if you have a column inside event_views that has the number of views, you could be looking for a sum isntead of count.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have put me on the right path. I will come back here when I have figured this out.